# Condensing duplicate rows into different columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-cleaning

I have a spreadsheet in excel that is the result of merging two queries to match an item to its category. In this case it would look something like this (using foods and their categories as a basic example):

[image: Raw data]

This was done so that I can see which categories are present for certain people (in this case represented by meal A, B, C...etc). I only care about some categories, so any foods that have not been sorted into a category can be removed from the list (like honey or oatmeal). I would like to organize my data so that any identical rows are removed, and any differing food categories are stacked next to each other in columns, such as this:

[image: Cleaned data]

In my actual spreadsheet I have several thousand values to work through, so something that works on a large scale would be helpful for cleaning up this data. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to use **PowerQuery** (included in Excel since Excel 2010) for such data transformations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to use PowerQuery to get most of the way there. I now have separate columns for each category; however there are a lot of blank cells as well. Is there a way to combine the rows that have blank cells in one column and data in another based on their ID (in this case the meal value)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some M-Code that will produce what you show for your desired results, given your original data.

The "magic" is in the `Table.Group` command/aggregation

If you have a varying number of Food Categories, may need some modification of the Splitter step so as to produce the correct numbers of columns:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table20"]}[Content],
    //#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Meal", type text}, {"Food", type text}, {"Food Category", type text}}),
    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Meal"}, {
        {"Food Category", each Text.Combine(
            List.RemoveNulls(
                List.Sort(
                    (List.Distinct([Food Category])))),";")}
    }),
    
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Food Category", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Food Category.1", "Food Category.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",
        {{"Food Category.1", type text}, {"Food Category.2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]